# Component is an OData Entity and thus a NavigationProperty

Tags: sitecore-commerce, odata

I am using Sitecore Commerce Experience 9 update-2, and want to add a custom child component to an entity.

The `Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Component` has a `Key` annotation (of type `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`).

```
namespace Sitecore.Commerce.Core
{
  public class Component
  {
    ...

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    ..
  }
}
```

This key annotation makes OData to generate a `EntityType` for components (or sub-classes of `Component`, e.g. `CustomComponent`).

```
<EntityType Name="CustomComponent" BaseType="Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Component">
    <Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String" />
</EntityType>
```

OData generates a `NavigationProperty` for entity types, for example:

```
<NavigationProperty Name="Components" Type="Collection(CustomComponent)" />
```

Navigation properties are by default not handled by the OData server.
Result of this is that child components (`ChildComponents` property on the `Component` class) cannot be easily added using the OOTB command controllers.

Only solution found so far is to implement a custom controller and method that adds a child component for a certain entity (e.g. an `AddChildComponentToCart` `CommandController` method).

Are there any other (cleaner, simpler) ways to add child components to an entity?

Any good reasons why a `Component` is not an OData complex type (this could be achieved by not having the `[Key]` annotation on the `Component` class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I passed this over to the Product Team to comment on this, and the response was.....

There is not need for a custom controller, all components and child components can be expanded using odata expand option, e.g.

```
{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/Carts('Cart01')?$expand=Lines($expand=CartLineComponents),Components

{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/SellableItems('Habitat_Master,6042134,')?$expand=Components($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents))))
```

Comment: Tried that, but the serializer only de-serializes the base `Component` class for child components. Any clues how to solve that?

Comment: Sitecore Support confirmed that the current approach for adding a custom component is to add your our Controller (and Block when necessary). Sadly not such a scalable approach.